# Contents of a .xib file are not shown when I run App. Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have a .xib file which has a few buttons, whose class is called `ContentView`.

[image: Set Class for xib]

Then I have setup the class as follows.

```
class ContentView: UIView {
    override init() {

        // Size doesn't matter
        super.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0: width: 500, height: 500))
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Now lets say I want to add this View in my main `ViewController` class
I use:

```
var contentView: ContentView = ContentView()
self.view.addSubview(contentView)
```

However contentView doesn't seem to be added to the my main view controller (well I can't see it so I presume it's not being added.)

Answer (score 1):

Follow this procedure for your  Xib

```
  vc : ViewController =  ViewController(nibName: "ViewController", bundle: nil) //change this to your class name

     self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

And make sure : You are using nibName otherwise your preloaded content of xib will not show .

Answer (score 0):

Instantiating a view like that does not use your xib file. Instead, you use 
[`-[NSBundle loadNibNamed:owner:options:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSBundle_UIKitAdditions/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSBundle/loadNibNamed:owner:options:) and provide the necessary input (nib name, owner, etc).

Another issue that will arise from using `- loadNibNamed:owner:options:` is that you call `fatalError` in your `initWithCoder:` implementation, which is used for nib instantiation by decoding. Instead, implement `initWithCoder:` properly.

Comment: I can't seem to figure out how to use `initWithCoder`, Xcode only suggests `init()`, `init(frame: CGRect())` and `init(coder aDecoder:  NSCoder)`

Comment: `initWithCoder:` is the Objective C name of `init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)`. In most cases, you don't even have to implement it to work. But since you did implement, and call `fatalError`, your app will crash. Remove the call to `fatalError` and it will work, once you use `- loadNibNamed:owner:options:`.

Comment: Yeah, the only thing is in Swift when you subclass a `UIView` `initWithCoder:` needs to be implemented. The problem I have now is that the view doesn't seem to appear.